# Does Lebron James have a say in roster trades

Tags: basketball, nba, transfer

There is a phrase call LeGM where Lebron is joked to trade you if you perform badly.  Does Lebron James or other influential players have a say on who to trade for or who they want on their team?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends what you mean by "a say". Teams always want to keep their superstars happy. One way to do that is to ensure they have the players they want around them, so teams will certainly ask their star players for their opinions on things, in much the same way as they'll talk to the coach. Quoting from [this recent ESPN article](https://www.espn.com/nba/story/_/id/33250361/los-angeles-lakers-feel-urgency-make-changes-trade-deadline-nears):

> James had a hand in Los Angeles' roster construction in the offseason, consulting with Rob Pelinka, Lakers vice president of basketball operations and general manager, on everything from the Westbrook trade with the Washington Wizards to free-agent signings, sources told ESPN. Pelinka will continue to collaborate with James leading up to the deadline in an attempt to improve the Lakers' chances of a deep run this season, sources told ESPN.

But the final decision always sits with the GM.